# TemplateDoesNotExist error due to a comment

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm in the process of making a website with Django and have yet to create order_snippet.html. When I add `{% include "order_snippet.html" %}` I expect a TemplateDoesNotExist error, but I put this in the payment.html and commented it out like this: `<!-- {% include "order_snippet.html" %} -->` yet I still have a TemplateDoesNotExist error. I thought comments weren't read by html? How come this raises an error?

Comment: The Django template engine always tries to generate everything, also things included in comments. The comment is just for rendering

Answer (score 0):

Django's template system knows nothing about HTML comments - it's a plain text templating system, you can use it to generate just any kind of text content. If you want to comment out part of the template code, [use the template system features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#comments).

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment the code with django comment template tags
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#comment

```
{% comment %} {% include "order_snippet.html" %} {% endcomment %}
```

if you still need `order_snippet.html` make sure the directory is included in the `settings.py`